# Check if document exists? Response payload doesn't have property exists

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to check if a document exists to do some if/else. I'm using angularfire2.

```
    this.angularFirestore.doc(`users/${credentials.user.uid}`)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Doing this I should have x.payload.exists but I actually don't.

```
{…}
payload: {…}
_document: Object { key: {…}, version: {…}, hasLocalMutations: true, … }
_firestore: Object { _queue: {…}, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: {…}, … }
_fromCache: true
_key: Object { path: {…} }
__proto__: Object { data: data(), get: get(), id: Getter, … }
type: "value"
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is in `x.payload.exists`.

The snapshot represents changes that have been made, you have to access the payload to know if it exists or not.

Example:

```
this.angularFirestore.doc(`users/${credentials.user.uid}`)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x.payload.exists))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but why it is not listed in the console output?

Comment: Have you tried to click on `{...}` in front of payload? you might see details in there. i'm not sure why the console behaves like this but I believe that's meant to avoid going to deep and spamming the console for one object.

Comment: It seemed weird to me because when I use the same on a collection I get the payload data printed in console.